# What is the difference between zero-padding and character-padding in Recurrent Neural Networks?

Tags: natural-language-processing, recurrent-neural-networks, seq2seq, padding

For RNN's to work efficiently, we vectorize the operations, which results in an input matrix of shape

```
(m, max_seq_len)
```

where `m` is the number of examples, e.g. sentences, and `max_seq_len` is the maximum length that a sentence can have. Some examples have smaller lengths than this `max_seq_len`. A solution is to pad these sentences.

One method to pad the sentences is called "zero-padding". This means that each sequence is padded with zeros. For example, given a vocabulary where each word is related to some index number, we can represent a sentence with length 4,

```
I am very confused
```

by

```
[23, 455, 234, 90]
```

Padding it to achieve a `max_seq_len=7`, we obtain a sentence represented by:

```
[23, 455, 234, 90, 0, 0, 0]
```

The index 0 is not part of the vocabulary.

Another method to pad is to add a padding character, e.g. `<<pad>>`, in our sentence:

```
I am very confused <<pad>>> <<pad>> <<pad>>
```

to achieve the `max_seq_len=7`. We also add `<<pad>>` in our vocabulary. Let's say its index is 1000. Then the sentence is represented by

```
[23, 455, 234, 90, 1000, 1000, 1000]
```

I have seen both methods used, but why is one used over the other? Are there any advantages or disadvantages comparing zero-padding with character-padding?

Comment: At least in Keras it is the default. Sure, you can pad_sequences and use a Masking layer with an arbitrary value. But the Embedding layer, the most frequent consumer of these encodings, provides a "mask_zero" boolean parameter.