# Is reconciling shape discrepancies the only purpose of padding?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, recurrent-neural-networks, padding

Padding is a technique used in some of the domains of artificial intelligence.

Data is generally available in different shapes. But in order to pass the data as input to a model in deep learning, the model allows only a particular shape of data to pass through it. And hence there is a need to allow padding in case if the input data shape contains dimensions that are less than the dimensions of the input of the model under consideration. For example, we [pad input sentences](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/26597/what-is-the-difference-between-zero-padding-and-character-padding-in-recurrent-n) in RNN to match the input shape of the RNN model. Sometimes we pad the input data in order to make a desired shape output. For example, padding is used in convolution operation to keep the size of feature maps intact.

Is handling this type of *shape issues* is the only purpose of padding? If no, what are the other purposes of padding that are not related to the shaping requirements of data?

Answer (score 1):

Learning "border effects" is another reason to use padding at least in convolutional neural networks. [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.02178.pdf) specifically looks at 2D CNNs for image processing. In my experience, I use pre-padding with 1D CNNs for NLP so my model can learn morphological affixes.

Comment: To put simply, padding is used to give priority to corner/border pixels/values, which are often ill-treated without padding!